# log DOM view of XML in firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm trying to send an XML node to the firebug console and when calling something like

```
console.log(myXML);
```

I see something like the below in the output panel

```
constructor     XML Document {}
```

expanding this takes me to a list of the XML DOM methods, etc, not the document itself.  I was hoping there was a way to trace out a DOM view of the node, similar to when you call console.log on an html element.  Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Thanks,

Comment: myXML.constructor might work, but I can't guarantee it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on XML elements, just not on the document itself. Try this:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString("<test></test>", "text/xml");  
console.log(doc.firstChild);
```

To print an outline from the document element, use the following:

```
console.dirxml(doc)
```